# Chunk nested lists starting on their deepest level

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, nested-loops

I would like to have a function that chunkes my list into a sublist, and then these sublists into further sublists, according to this scheme. The number of nestings and block_sizes will vary. Please be aware of the [4] and [9] in lst2, this is essential.

```
block_sizes = [5, 2, 1]
my_lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

# desired return
lst1 = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11]] # chunked into sublists of size 5
lst2 = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9], [10, 11]] # chunked into sublists of size 2; be aware of [4] and [9]
lst3 = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], ... [11]]
```

I already tried this, but the chunking does not work as intended:

```
block_sizes = [5, 2, 1]

def chunk_into_list(lst, chunk_size):
    return [lst[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(lst), chunk_size)]

for i, block_size in enumerate(block_sizes):

    for step in range(len(block_sizes[:(i + 1)])):
        my_lst = chunk_in_sizes(my_lst, block_sizes[step])

    print(my_lst)
```

But this leads to:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11]]
[[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], [[10, 11]]]
[[[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]], [[[10, 11]]]]
```

I will be using this for simulations, so efficiency would be important, if possible.

Comment: btw don’t use list as a variable name.

Comment: I am aware of that, thanks. It's just for the sake of presenting my problem.

Comment: If you are aware of that, then please don’t propagate this mistake for the millions of future programmers to make.

Comment: You have a point there, I corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that it's not the most optimal way, but as far as i understand it will do what you want.

```
block_sizes = [5, 2, 1]
my_lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

def chunk_into_list(lst, chunk_size):
    if lst and isinstance(lst[0], list):
        lst_new = []
        for nested_lst in lst:
            lst_new += (chunk_into_list(nested_lst, chunk_size))
        return lst_new
    else:
        return [lst[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(lst), chunk_size)]


for i, block_size in enumerate(block_sizes):
    for step in range(len(block_sizes[:(i + 1)])):
        my_lst = chunk_into_list(my_lst, block_sizes[step])

    print(my_lst)

#Output
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11]]
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9], [10, 11]]
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much (and all the other contributors)! Yes, this leads to the desired result! I would appreciate a more efficient solution, but this would also do.

Comment: I can't reproduce it yet. Sometimes I get the error "if isinstance(lst[0], list):
IndexError: list index out of range" Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: This may happen if list lst in chunk_into_list is empty. To avoid this you should do something like that: replace "if isinstance(lst[0], list):" with "if lst and isinstance(lst[0], list):".

In this case if-condition returns False because the list is empty, and second part (isinstance(lst[0], list)) won't even be checked.

Comment: Thanks again! That seems to work. I was not sure if this would change the overall result

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
for block_size in block_sizes:
    print(chunk_in_sizes(lst, block_size))
```

Comment: No, that is not what I need. Please mind list2 in my desired result, where [4] and [9] are the only elements in their sublist, as they were in one of the 5-element-lists before.